# Is there a way to evaluate a variable in a fragment without th:insert

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a fragment that looks like

```
<th:block th:fragment="link-url">[[${Subscription_link}]]</th:block>
```

`Subscription_link` is a variable.

Now I want to pass the value of fragment to a variable in th:with like

```
<a th:with="url=~{link-url}"></a>
```

but this doesnt work as when I try to print the result like

`<div>[[link-url/text()}]]</div>` I get `<TH:BLOCKTH:TEXT="${SUBSCRIPTION_LINK}"></TH:BLOCK>`

But when I use `<th:block th:insert="~{link-url}" />` the value gets properly evaluated and printed out. But then I cant use this inside a th:with. So kinda stuck.